# how to dynamically sum fields in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am newbie to mongodb, and have some dynamic fields (var1, var2 , var3 ... varN), have the variable names in HashMap, the fields are Double fields, how do I summarize dynamic fields in mongodb? I tried the following code snippet :

```
  ProjectionOperation operation = new ProjectionOperation ();
      operation.andInclude((String[])map.values().toArray());

        agg = newAggregation(operation, 
                group((String[])map.values().toArray()));
```

I am not able to put sum of the dynamic fields. Is there any way out?

regards

kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hats off to spring-data-mongodb. Was able to write a reasonable query with spring-data-mongodb. Hope it may be useful for others.

```
 Aggregation agg2 = null;   
 GroupOperation t = null;
 List<RenderReport> result=null;

Fields fields =Fields.fields(vars);//vars is as string array containing variable names var1, var2 and so on 
                t = group( fields().and("year") );
  Iterator<org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Field> fieldIt=fields.iterator();
  while(fieldIt.hasNext())
  {
      org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Field f =  fieldIt.next();

     t= t.sum(f.getName()).as(f.getName());    
  }
   agg2 = newAggregation(
              project( vars  )
                          .andExpression("units * retailPrice").as("grossSales")
                        .andExpression("year(mydate)").as("year"),
                 t,
                  sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "year")
                 );

     AggregationResults<RenderReport> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg2,RenderReport.class,
             RenderReport.class);

      result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

regards

kris